# How to Change dictionary values in python file from another file

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.7

I would like to change values in a Dict in another file. File1.py contains the code to edit the Dict, File2.py contains the Dict itself.

File1.py is generating a code to replace `BTOK` values only.

File1.py:

```py
with open('file2.py', 'r') as file :
    filedata = file.read()
    print (filedata.str(BTK['btk1']))
    for line in filedata:
        line['btk1'] = BTok
with open('file2.py', 'w') as file:
    file.write(line)
```

File2.py:

```py
c = {
    'id' : 'C80e3ce43c3ea3e8d1511ec',
    'secret' : 'c10c371b4641010a750073925b0857'
}
rk = {
    't1' : 'ZTkwMGE1MGEt',
}
BTK = {
    'BTok' : '11eyJhbGc'
}
```

Comment: Question is not clear, can you please elaborate? Want to replace `11eyJhbGc` to some other value in file2.py?

Comment: sorry so i wanna replace the value for BTok only in file2. so my file1 i have some code that generates a new key and then i wanna replace that key in file2 under BTOK key

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this reliably, that is, so it works whether your strings are quoted with `'`, `"` or `"""`, for whatever values they have and whatever newlines you want to put around values, then you may want to use [`ast`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html) to parse the source code and modify it. The only inconvenient with this is that module cannot, by itself, generate code, so you would need to install some additional dependency such as [`astor`](https://astor.readthedocs.io/), for what is essentially a rather menial task. In any case, here is how you could do it that way:

```py
import ast
import astor

# To read from file:
# with open('file2.py', 'r') as f: code = f.read()
code = """
c = {
    'id' : 'C80e3ce43c3ea3e8d1511ec',
    'secret' : 'c10c371b4641010a750073925b0857'
}
rk = {
    't1' : 'ZTkwMGE1MGEt',
}
BTK = {
    'BTok' : '11eyJhbGc'
}
"""

# Value to replace
KEY = 'BTok'
NEW_VALUE = 'new_btok'
# Parse code
m = ast.parse(code)
# Go through module statements
for stmt in m.body:
    # Only look at assignments
    if not isinstance(stmt, ast.Assign): continue
    # Take right-hand side of the assignment
    value = stmt.value
    # Only look at dict values
    if not isinstance(value, ast.Dict): continue
    # Look for keys that match what we are looking for
    replace_idx = [i for i, k in enumerate(value.keys)
                   if isinstance(k, ast.Str) and k.s == KEY]
    # Replace corresponding values
    for i in replace_idx:
        value.values[i] = ast.Str(NEW_VALUE)

new_code = astor.to_source(m)
# To write to file:
# with open(`file2.py', 'w') as f: f.write(new_code)
print(new_code)
# c = {'id': 'C80e3ce43c3ea3e8d1511ec', 'secret':
#     'c10c371b4641010a750073925b0857'}
# rk = {'t1': 'ZTkwMGE1MGEt'}
# BTK = {'BTok': 'new_btok'}
```

Comment: But i am tryin to just change the value for BTok1 ( and in my other script i already changed the value)

BTK = {
    'BTok' : '11eyJhbGc'
    }